Authorship of class notes written by students
Recently in my department we decided to re-organize the teaching program. For this reason, I had to prepare almost from scratch a new course, which I taught this semester.
The course is on a topic on which I do actual research, so I was happy to do that, but it was also quite an effort, as I had to prepare a lot of slides, while some parts with heavy mathematics, which I taught using the blackboard, were provided as handwritten notes.
The priority was to give the students enough material to prepare the exam, in a form that was "good enough". I had a plan to write everything down on a proper electronic document, but of course this will take time.
With my great surprise, at the end of the semester I discovered that a group of students decided to write down their notes of the course electronically (using LaTeX). They also reproduced the graphs I drew on the blackboard using computer programs. They were so kind to give me all the material, even the source code.
I asked if I could provide this material to all the students, and they gladly accepted.
Of course, I will have to revise everything and add some missing parts, but not starting from zero will save me a lot of time.
Now, my question is about the authorship of the notes that will be distributed: what would be a proper way to give everyone the right credits for their work? To be specific, I am thinking to 3 possible strategies:

Put the teacher and all the students in the author list on the first page of the notes. However, maybe this can be confusing because the students did not develop the actual content of the notes.
Put the teacher as author on the first page, and the students in an acknowledgements section, or in the preface, or something equivalent.
A "middle way", which I would prefer: put the teacher as author, and the students as something like "Notes prepared by", both on the first page. Maybe add anyway some acknowledgements to properly thank the students for their work.

Before proceeding, I would like to know if there are rules on this, or some guidelines.

Do the students provide intellectual content of their own or simply capture your ideas? Is what they wrote "creative"?

#3 looks fair. It makes clear who did what and gives proper credit. No misunderstandings. It does not make clear who owns the copyright, but for that, you ideally would need to consult an expert. I suspect the copyright is either with you or the university, but I am not a lawyer.

@Buffy I would say no creative work, they just put my explanation in a written form.

The students acted as scribes and have no right to authorship. However, since without them, the document would not exist, you can give them authorship and explain the genesis of the document in an introduction. The problem with that solution would come later, if a student claims rights accruing from authorship, because you decide to make the lecture notes into a book. For example, take a student who claims in twenty years that that student wrote a book with you in order to foster their career, but you would not give that student a recommendation. Other problems could arise if you would derive creative work from these lecture notes. The problem with leaving the students out is the lack of acknowledgment of their work, but that seems to be the lesser evil.
Authors who employ a proof-reader that also makes suggestions for clarity and checks for accuracy (i.e. a doctoral student in academia) have the same conundrum. At one point of increasing involvement, the proof-reader turns into a co-author. Not only is there a sliding scale, but in addition, different cultures have different attitudes about the meaning of authorship. The only thing we know is that someone acting as a secretary is not entitled to authorship, whereas someone who writes substantial text that is incorporated into the work is a co-author.
